# Duplicity backup script for S3 fails on CentOS 5

Tags: duplicity

Hi I have not been able to setup backup to S3 using this guide:
http://www.cenolan.com/2008/12/how-to-incremental-daily-backups-amazon-s3-duplicity/

I get this error when I run the script:
    Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 0
    Enter 'duplicity --help' for help screen.

The duplicity log file:
    2013-08-07_17:43:20: ... backing up filesystem
    ./duplicity-backup: line 60: --include=/home: No such file or directory

My script is like this:

```
!/bin/bash

# Set up some variables for logging
LOGFILE="/var/log/backup.log"
DAILYLOGFILE="/var/log/backup.daily.log"
HOST='hostname'
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
MAILADDR="user@domain.com"

# Clear the old daily log file
cat /dev/null > ${DAILYLOGFILE}

# Trace function for logging, don't change this
trace () {
        stamp=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`
        echo "$stamp: $*" >> ${DAILYLOGFILE}
}

# Export some ENV variables so you don't have to type anything
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxx"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
export PASSPHRASE="xx"

# Your GPG key
GPG_KEY=xxxx

# How long to keep backups for
OLDER_THAN="1M"

# The source of your backup
SOURCE=/

# The destination
# Note that the bucket need not exist
# but does need to be unique amongst all
# Amazon S3 users. So, choose wisely.
DEST="s3+http://xxxx"

FULL=
if [ $(date +%d) -eq 1 ]; then
        FULL=full
fi;

trace "Backup for local filesystem started"

trace "... removing old backups"

duplicity remove-older-than ${OLDER_THAN} ${DEST} >> ${DAILYLOGFILE} 2>&1

trace "... backing up filesystem"

duplicity \
    ${FULL} \
    --encrypt-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --sign-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --volsize=250 \
#    --include=/vhosts \
#    --include=/etc \
    --include=/home \
    --include=/root \
    --exclude=/** \
    ${SOURCE} ${DEST} >> ${DAILYLOGFILE} 2>&1

trace "Backup for local filesystem complete"
trace "------------------------------------"

# Send the daily log file by email
cat "$DAILYLOGFILE" | mail -s "Duplicity Backup Log for $HOST - $DATE" $MAILADDR

# Append the daily log file to the main log file
cat "$DAILYLOGFILE" >> $LOGFILE

# Reset the ENV variables. Don't need them sitting around
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
export PASSPHRASE=
```

Does anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove commented lines from script execution. From:

```
duplicity \
    ${FULL} \
    --encrypt-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --sign-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --volsize=250 \
#    --include=/vhosts \
#    --include=/etc \
    --include=/home \
    --include=/root \
    --exclude=/** \
    ${SOURCE} ${DEST} >> ${DAILYLOGFILE} 2>&1
```

to

```
duplicity \
    ${FULL} \
    --encrypt-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --sign-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --volsize=250 \
    --include=/home \
    --include=/root \
    --exclude=/** \
    ${SOURCE} ${DEST} >> ${DAILYLOGFILE} 2>&1
```